# Angular how to await for one subscribe to continue

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I await for a subscribe to continue my code sequence?

My subscribe is into a function, but I just want that this function finish if this subscribe execute.

My Subscribe:

```
this.massService.getMass(token, userId).subscribe((data: IMass) => {
    // Execution
})
```

My Service

```
getMass(token: string, userId: string): Observable<IMass> {
    const httpParams = new HttpParams().set('userId', userId);

    const options = {
        params: httpParams,
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
    };
    return this.http.get<IMass>(environment.apiUrl + '/mass', options);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert observable to promise like :-

```
this.massService.getMass(token, userId).pipe(take(1),tap((res) => //execution)).toPromise();
```

And use await like you use with promise.

Comment: It gave me an idea and it's works. I had "forEach" and into this the await wasn't executing, but your code helped me to notice this and I am using this solution with a `for` instead `forEach`. Thanks!